# configure, if only newer version of the required lib available

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, libboost

I'd like to ./configure a software, that requires:

- libboost1.35-dev
- libboost-filesystem1.35-dev
- libboost-thread1.35-dev

My distribution (Ubuntu 9.10) has only 1.40, and the configuration process fails with message:

```
libboost1.35-dev library is not installed.
```

Is it the expected behaviour or a bug? Is there a way to configure this program with v1.40 packages? Is it a good solution to break somehow the dependency checking?

Answer (score 1):

There may be functionality differences between the libraries so I would make every effort to install the additional older libraries first(apt-file search libboost1.35). If that fails you can attempt to symlink the existing libboost libs to the older names and rebuild your ldcache and re-run ./configure.

Comment: I have no 1.53, I'm trying symlink them.